# Help with step in paper unclear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

I am referring to a paper by : https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Robertson-1-0755734.pdf 
The notation is simple enough to understand, however i having trouble with line 16.

Said that "we have $|F(s)|$ < $\frac{1}{s}$, which gives $\displaystyle\lim_{s \to \infty}F(s)=0$"$~~~$I just don't understand why?

And, Where and how $|F(s)|$ < $\frac{1}{s}$ come from?

I think ,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle |F(s)|&=\left|\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\text{sin}~x}{x}e^{-sx} dx\right|\\
&\leqslant\int_0^{\infty}\left|\frac{\text{sin}~x}{x}e^{-sx}\right| dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\left|\frac{\text{sin}~x}{x}\right|e^{-sx} dx\\
&< \int_0^{\infty}1e^{-sx} dx\\
&=\frac{1}{s}
\end{align*}
But I'm not sure it's correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that since $|F(s)| < \frac{1}{s}$ then $-\frac{1}{s} < F(s) < \frac{1}{s}$. Since $-\frac{1}{s}$ and $\frac{1}{s}$ both go to $0$ in the limit, by the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) we have that $F$ goes to $0$ also.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty} |F(s)|$. We know that:

$\lim\limits_{s\to\infty} |F(s)|\leq \lim\limits_{s\to\infty}\frac{1}{s}=0$, and so:

$|\lim\limits_{s\to\infty}F(s)|=0$, so $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty}F(s)=0$.